# Minikube Kubernetes pending pod on AWS EC2

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I've tried many times to install kubernetes on Debian last stable version on AWS EC2 instance (2 vcpu, 4 GB RAM, 10 GB HD).
I've also tried to install now on ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1084-aws x86_64) over AWS EC2 same vm compute configuration.

I've installed docker, kubctl, docker-cri, crictl and minikube but I've an issue with Kubernetes node not ready and then pending pods. The blocking point here for me is the CNI as I've core-dns pods pending and I see few strange things in the logs, but do not know how to solve it.
I've tried also to install Calico as you will see the calico pods. It's the first time I install Kubernetes and Minikube.

Minikube is started with the following command : minikube start --vm-driver=none

minikube version: v1.27.1

root@awsec2:~# minikube status
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured

root@awsec2:~# docker version
Client:
Version:           20.10.7
API version:       1.41
Go version:        go1.13.8
Git commit:        20.10.7-0ubuntu5~18.04.3
Built:             Mon Nov  1 01:04:14 2021
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Context:           default
Experimental:      true

root@ip-172-31-37-142:~#  kubectl get node -o wide
NAME               STATUS     ROLES           AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
ip-awsec2-ip   NotReady   control-plane   10h   v1.25.2   172.31.37.142           Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS   5.4.0-1084-aws   docker://20.10.7

root@aws:~# kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE         NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
default           hello-minikube                             0/1     Pending   0             10h
kube-system       coredns-565d847f94-kmbdr                   0/1     Pending   0             11h
kube-system       etcd-ip-172-31-37-142                      1/1     Running   1 (10h ago)   11h
kube-system       kube-apiserver-ip-172-31-37-142            1/1     Running   1 (10h ago)   11h
kube-system       kube-controller-manager-ip-172-31-37-142   1/1     Running   1 (10h ago)   11h
kube-system       kube-proxy-dff99                           1/1     Running   1 (10h ago)   11h
kube-system       kube-scheduler-ip-172-31-37-142            1/1     Running   1 (10h ago)   11h
kube-system       storage-provisioner                        0/1     Pending   0             11h
tigera-operator   tigera-operator-6675dc47f4-gngrn           1/1     Running   2 (7m ago)    10h

In the minikube logs command I've seen this error but do not know how to solve it :

- ==> kubelet <==
- -- Logs begin at Tue 2022-10-18 21:26:09 UTC, end at Wed 2022-10-19 08:57:51 UTC. --
  Oct 19 08:52:52 ip-172-31-37-142 kubelet[17361]: E1019 08:52:52.018304   17361 kubelet.go:2373] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized"

If someone can explain how to correct that as it's should be very standard issue.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Now, I've found a workaround that will work for my test.
I've run Minikube with Kubernetes 1.23 instead of 1.24.
I've run this command :

```
minikube start --vm-driver=none --kubernetes-version=v1.23.0
```

I didn't set up Calico CNI now, I have successfully my node and hello-World pod running correctly.
I will test it like that, then I will try to upgrade to Kube 1.24.

Kind Regards,